# Getting an empty response from express+NodeJS with POST request

Tags: node.js, express

Learning nodeJS so pardon the beginner question I would like to create API endpoints for methods to post and get data from my server.

However, whenever I try to create a new entry with these endpoints on postman my response only returns the id associated with the entry, whereas I should be receiving the id,name and bio. Secondly, I have a validator that should check whether or not a name and bio have been entered before returning a response (if either of these have not been entered, the response should be an error message). When I added my if else statements I only receive the error message regardless of whether I sent a bio and name

Here is my code (model.js):

```
const insert = ({ name, bio }) => {
  const newUser = { id: getId(), name, bio }
  users.push(newUser)
  return Promise.resolve(newUser)
}
```

and my endpoints

```
const express = require('express')
const Model = require('./users/model')
const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    let { name, bio } = req.body;
    let model = req.body;
    if(name && bio) {
        Model.insert(name,bio)
            .then(elem => {
                res.status(201).json(model);
            })
    }
    else {
        console.log(name)
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Please provide name and bio for the user"})
    }
})
```

FYI: My console.log returns `undefined`

Comment: what does json are you sending through Postman, can you give me an example?

Comment: also what does your `users model` look like, normally you wouldn't be pushing a new user into an array, rather you would be creating a new instance of that model.

Comment: Maybe make sure you're sending through Raw->JSON format the body, since you're destructure it

Comment: Your Model.insert function needs to be called like this
`Model.insert({ name, bio })` because it receives a single argument that is an object with name and bio properties and not two arguments.